# Need to print out all links on a sidebar in selenium (xpath?)

Tags: perl, xpath, selenium

I need to find any extra links and print them out. I started by doing:

```
get_xpath_count('//li/a')
```

and comparing it to the size of an array that holds the name of all the links for the sidebar. When the count is too high/low, I need to print out all the extra/missing links. I would like to make a list of the names so I can compare it to the array. I've tried a few things like `get_text('//li/a')`, which returns the name of the first. `get_text('//li/a[1])` does the same, but any other index returns nothing.

Any ideas? Also, I need the name that's displayed on the link, not the actual href.

Edit*  Also, i'm pretty new to selenium and Xpath. Please let me know if there's info I let out that is needed, or just any suggestions towards thew way I'm going about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get this to work using [CSS element locators](http://search.cpan.org/~mattp/Test-WWW-Selenium/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm#Element_Locators). Since I use CSS selectors far more often than Xpath, I find it easier to always use them with Selenium as well.

```
$selenium->get_text("css=li a:nth-child(1)")
$selenium->get_text("css=li a:nth-child(2)")
$selenium->get_text("css=li a:nth-child(...)")
$selenium->get_text("css=li a:nth-child(n)")
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working entirely correct. It's returning the [-] icon next to the link meant for collapsing.

Comment: Without seeing the actual HTML you are working with it would be difficult for me to give you a fully working example. You should just be able to modify the CSS selector as needed.

Comment: I hate to pester you on this, but I tried and with no luck. I continually get results that don't make sense to me. This is the part of the html:

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
(//li/a)[$someNumber]
```

this will get you the text of `$someNumber`-th `//li/a` in the XML document.

**In order to know what values to use to substitute the `$someNumber` with, you need to know the total count of these elements**:

```
count(//li/a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in JAVA. You can use the same concept in perl

```
int totCountInPage=selenium.getXpathCount(//li/a);
for(int count=1;count<=totCountInPage;count++)
System.out.println(selenium.getText("xpath=//li[count]/a"));
```

This should print text inside the anchor links under all li tag.